# ASP.Net: label control in panel not updating

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, label, panel, modalpopupextender

I have an ASP panel with a modalpopupextender attached to it that is shown dynamically. Within the panel there are two labels that are dynamically populated with text when the panel popup is shown. however, when it is shown the labels are blank (missing). Below is my code for the HTML markup and code behind:

HTML MARKUP

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlalert" runat="server" CssClass="modal">
    <div class="rel">
        <div class="modal-inner-wrapper-alert rounded-corners">
            <div class="content rounded-corners">
                <div class="body">
                    <div class="popuppanel">
                        <div class="popupGnrl-Alert">
                            <asp:Label ID="alerttitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
                            <asp:Label ID="alertlabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="section" runat="server" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="violation" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="popupGnrl-Alert" style="text-align:center;">
                            <asp:Button ID="cmdMaxAlertOk" runat="server" Text="Yes" Width="50px" 
                                onclick="cmdMaxAlertOk_Click" />&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="cmdMaxAlertCancel" 
                                runat="server" Text="No" Width="50px" onclick="cmdMaxAlertCancel_Click" />
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpealert" runat="server" TargetControlID="popuplnk" PopupControlID="pnlalert" >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

ASP.NET Code Behind

```
            this.mpealert.Show();
            this.alerttitle.Text = "Submission time exceeded";
            this.alertlabel.Text = "This expense was incurred greater than 3 months ago and is therefore outside of the normal claim period. Do you still wish to proceed?  NOTE: expense may be rejected by Finance.";
```

What could be causing the labels not to show?

Comment: Did you try setting the text and then calling `Show()`?

Comment: Yes I just tried that before I got your comment and it still didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you setting the text of the labels in the button event which shows the modal popup extender?

If so, the "show" event is probably being handled client side and your server side text setting code is probably never being called.

Wrap your modalpopupextender in an UpdatePanel and set it's Update condition to Always.

Comment: This worked beautifully thank you very much. makes perfect sense that the changing of the value of the label was being done within the button click at a different time.

Comment: Read up on UpdatePanels etc... if you haven't.  They're very easy to implement, but aren't the greatest choices to use.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not work for me. If we keep the panel inside an update panel and call the update method on update panel, then the contents get updated.